# Javascript best practice to use undefined as boolean evaluation?

Tags: javascript

In this simple javascript code, method verify returns a string if conditions do not match, else undefined. I am using undefined value in 'if' clause. Is this common / acceptable javascript programming practice?

```
if (verify(text)) {
   alert(text + " is not bar");
}

function verify(foo) {
  if (foo + "" != "bar") return "foo is not same as bar";
}
```

Comment: Why not return `true` if foo is not bar?

Comment: A verification method should return a boolean.

Comment: Yeah, ideally, the function should be `return foo + "" != "bar";` (esp if the user has a Java background), but I see this code as something someone is playing with to see how a new language works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since you know the verification outcomes will be either truthy (a non-empty string) or falsy (undefined), it's perfectly fine to use it like that.

Here's a list of truthy and falsy values in JS, you might find them handy: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Answer (score 0):

It is a common practise but in my experience its better to be explicit. For instance, I prefer:

```
verify(text) === undefined
```

The way I would suggest is to make the 'verify' to return a boolean value. The reason for this, is if for whatever reason you have a verification method that returns 0 (zero) and you do `if (verify)`, the condition will be false but 0 is actually a verified value.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is technically possible and works fine in most cases, I personally find it better style to design functions so that they always return the same type. My IDE warns me about inconsistent functions:

[image]

and this warning should be taken seriously. In particular, it helps you avoid unpleasant surprises when you test your app:

```
// hmm...
function isZero(n) {
    if(n == 0)
        return true;
}

// let's test it
describe("test", function() {
    it("isZero", function() {
        expect(isZero(0)).toBe(true);
        expect(isZero(1)).toBe(false); // FAILURE!
    });
});
```